# Unique values of date

Tags: java, list, csv, random

I am writing in a CSV and my calendar is doubling values ... I couldn't figure out the problem.
PS: Amount is like 1.000.000 or 10.000.000.

```
    public static void CSV(String path, int amount) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(1980, 01, 01);
    for (; set.size() < amount;) {
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 2);
        set.add(c.getTime());
    }
    Iterator<Date> it = set.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        csvWriter.append(dateFormat.format(it.next()));
    }
    ...
}
```

Well, the error was the Hour in am/pm (1-12). 
Thanks to @Teemu.

Comment: what do you mean by "doubling values"?

Comment: do not create `new Random()` every time

Comment: The first for loop is not putting unique values into the set.

Comment: Your code is generating unique date values just fine. Are you sure you want to use HashSet? The Set-interface's Iterator will not give you the values in the same order as you are putting them in. Use List-inteface (for example ArrayList) if you want to keep the order the same.

Comment: @Hua duplicate values

Comment: @Teemu Doesnt matter the order... But my code is not generating a unique date values, its duplicating. I don't know if it's because the quantity is more than 1,000,000 values

Comment: Ok, another question. Do you mean "doubling values" by that the same time occus twice? If that is the case, I think I know what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean "doubling values" by that the same time occurs twice. Reason for that is your date formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

You are formatting hours as `'hh'`. Meaning that it is formatting date as [Hour in am/pm (1-12)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) . So two time values are actually unique, one is AM and another is PM. You are not providing the AM / PM markings into SimpleDateFormat and that's why both time values looks the same.

If you want to distinquish the AM / PM markings change the format to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aaa");
```

Or another way is to format hours in 0-23 format

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Not sure if my assumption is correct but I hope this helps.